# Split a list after a string and creating a new list of lists

Tags: python

I would like to split a long list into pieces after the string "Title". Given is a list with this structure:

```
l = ["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5", "Title ghi", "text4", "text5" ...]
```

and the output should be:

```
new = [["Title abc", "text1", "text"], ["Title def", "text4", "text5"], ["Title ghi", "text4", "text5"]]
```

The start is always `"Title"` and it is also the delimiter for the next match. I tried

```
re.findall ('Title.*Title).dx', l, re.DOTALL)
```

but this will stop at `"Title ghi"`. How would you do that?

Comment: Is `l` always like `Title xxx` followed by 2 `text`? If yes, then slicing is better option than using `re`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the indices of "Title" and slice the list by them

```
l = ["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5", "Title ghi", "text4", "text5"]
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(l) if 'Title' in s]
indices.append(len(l)) # add from last "Title" to the end

new = [l[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in range(len(indices)-1)]
print(new)

# Output: [['Title abc', 'text1', 'text'], ['Title def', 'text4', 'text5'], ['Title ghi', 'text4', 'text5']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to answers above but extending for any iterable - you can build a generator of unique values that increments in value each time the criteria is met, then use that as part of a `itertools.groupby` to build the sub-lists, eg:

```
from itertools import accumulate, groupby

groups = accumulate(el.startswith('Title') for el in data)
out = [[el[1] for el in g] for _, g in groupby(zip(groups, data), lambda L: L[0])]
```

Will given `data` of:

```
['Title abc',
 'text1',
 'text',
 'more text',
 'Title def',
 'text4',
 'Title x',
 'Title ghi',
 'text4',
 'text5']
```

Give you an `out` of:

```
[['Title abc', 'text1', 'text', 'more text'],
 ['Title def', 'text4'],
 ['Title x'],
 ['Title ghi', 'text4', 'text5']]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the format of the list is consistent with your example, you can just slice the list:

```
new = [l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]

print(new)

>>> [['Title abc', 'text1', 'text'], ['Title def', 'text4', 'text5'], ['Title ghi', 'text4', 'text5']]
```

Answer (score 3):

this is also a version:

```
l = ["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5", "Title ghi",
     "text4", "text5"]

res = []
tmp = []
for item in l:
    if item.startswith("Title"):
        if tmp:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp = []
    tmp.append(item)
if tmp:
    res.append(tmp)

print(res)
# [['Title abc', 'text1', 'text'], ['Title def', 'text4', 'text5'], ['Title ghi', 'text4', 'text5']]
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different way, in case your accompanying elements are not constant:

```
>>> l = ["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5",
         "Title ghi", "text4", "text5"]
>>> [('Title'+s).strip(',').split(',') for s in ','.join(l).split('Title') if s]
[['Title abc', 'text1', 'text'],
 ['Title def', 'text4', 'text5'],
 ['Title ghi', 'text4', 'text5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

more explanatory version

```
old = ["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5", "Title ghi", "text4", "text5" ]
new=[]
for i in range(0,len(old),3):
    new.append([old[i],old[i+1],old[i+2]])
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
given_list=["Title abc", "text1", "text", "Title def", "text4", "text5", "Title ghi", "text4", "text5" ]
required_list=[]

for i in range(0,len(given_list),3):
    required_list.append(given_list[i:i+3]);


print(required_list)
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on your answer a bit more, maybe by explaining the code a bit more.